# How to mock a static method of util class of a package using spring dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, powermock

I have a package using spring dependency injection for its unit tests using following code.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "<xml_location>" })
@WebAppConfiguration
```

I need to add a static method in the util class and need to mock it to prevent existing unit tests to fail. I tried using PowerMock but getting different errors like the following ones.

```
<class_name> not prepared for test.
org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException
```

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

Can someone please point to an example where this was done before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mockito for that. In latest versions it has `Mockito.mockStatic()` method.
Here is an example

```
@Test
public void staticTest() {
    MockedStatic<GoogleDriveHelper> staticMock = Mockito.mockStatic(GoogleDriveHelper.class);
    staticMock.when(() -> GoogleDriveHelper.fixFileNameExtension(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("Blablabla");
    assertEquals("Blablabla", GoogleDriveHelper.fixFileNameExtension("abc", "bcd"));
}
```